# Google Chart - tailoring views - column indexes 0-4

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

In order to reduce the number of fetches from database, I fetch all my data at once, and then tailor it with different views for more charts. In this case I have data table with ten columns (from 0 to 9) and want to show column 0 as X axis, 1 as AreaChart and additional two columns as lines on Combo Chart. Everithing works if I take columns up to 4. If I take e.g. column 7 with `view.setColumns` Google gives error message `"Invalid column index 7. Should be an integer in the range [0-4]."` Why indexes only 0-4 !!!???

Here it is how it looks like:

```js
    google.charts.load('current',{callback:init,'packages':['corechart'],'language':'hr'});
    
    function init()
    {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date','Datum');
      data.addColumn('number','Vrijednost');
      data.addColumn('number','Relativna promjena');
      data.addColumn('number','Kontinuiranost promjene');
      data.addColumn('number','Prosjek obični u preth. 5 dana');
      data.addColumn('number','Prosjek težinski u preth. 5 dana');
      data.addColumn('number','Trend prema preth. 5 dana');
      data.addColumn('number','Prosjek obični u preth. 10 dana');
      data.addColumn('number','Prosjek težinski u preth. 10 dana');
      data.addColumn('number','Trend prema preth. 10 dana');
      data.addRows([
[new Date('2017-07-07'),11.92850,-0.13,-1,-3,-2.33333,11.96977,-5.5,-4,11.93431],
[new Date('2017-07-10'),11.94040,0.1,0,-3,-2.33333,11.9698,-5.5,-4,11.93224],
[new Date('2017-07-11'),11.96360,0.19,1,-3,-2.33333,11.95871,-5.5,-4,11.94423],
[new Date('2017-07-12'),11.95520,-0.07,0,-3,-2.33333,11.94968,-5.5,-4,11.96142],
[new Date('2017-07-13'),11.93310,-0.18,-1,-3,-2.33333,11.96335,-5.5,-4,11.97571],
[new Date('2017-07-14'),11.94130,0.07,0,-3,-2.33333,11.95136,-5.5,-4,11.97237],
[new Date('2017-07-17'),11.89760,-0.37,-1,-3,-2.33333,11.93811,-5.5,-4,11.96705],
[new Date('2017-07-18'),11.91230,0.12,0,-3,-2.33333,11.89439,-5.5,-4,11.93777],
[new Date('2017-07-19'),11.93750,0.21,1,-3,-2.33333,11.89151,-5.5,-4,11.91419],
[new Date('2017-07-20'),11.96080,0.2,2,-3,-2.33333,11.9183,-5.5,-4,11.9194],
[new Date('2017-07-21'),12.01040,0.41,3,-3,-2.33333,11.95357,-5.5,-4,11.93201],
[new Date('2017-07-24'),12.03320,0.19,4,-3,-2.33333,12.02595,-5.5,-4,11.95908],
[new Date('2017-07-25'),12.06780,0.29,5,-3,-2.33333,12.06525,-5.5,-4,11.99299],
[new Date('2017-07-26'),12.06780,0,5,-3,-2.33333,12.10184,-5.5,-4,12.04073],
[new Date('2017-07-27'),12.09690,0.24,6,-3,-2.33333,12.10942,-5.5,-4,12.07929],
[new Date('2017-07-28'),12.11120,0.12,7,-3,-2.33333,12.1175,-5.5,-4,12.11609],
[new Date('2017-07-31'),12.11100,-0,0,-3,-2.33333,12.13091,-5.5,-4,12.14988],
[new Date('2017-08-01'),12.14890,0.31,1,-3,-2.33333,12.12988,-5.5,-4,12.16061],
[new Date('2017-08-02'),12.06400,-0.7,0,-3,-2.33333,12.16005,-5.5,-4,12.17619],
[new Date('2017-08-03'),12.10260,0.32,1,-3,-2.33333,12.09797,-5.5,-4,12.14875]]);

      var ComboOpt = {
        height: 400,
        annotations: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}, highContrast: true},
        animation:{ duration: 500, easing: 'out', startup: true },
        vAxis: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}},
        hAxis: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}, gridlines: {count: 30}, showTextEvery: 7},
        chartArea: {width: '80%', height: '80%'},
        legend: {position: 'bottom'},
        series: {0: {type: 'area', color: "blue", pointsVisible: true}, 
                 1: {type: 'line'}, 
                 2: {type: 'line'}}
      };
      
      var view1a = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view1a.setColumns([0,1,{sourceColumn:1,role:'annotation'},3,4]);
      var chart1a = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('Chart1a'));      
      chart1a.draw(view1a,ComboOpt);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="Chart1a"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a bug when using a `DataView` with `animation.startup: true`

an easy fix, while keeping animation on startup,
is to convert the view back to a data table --> `view1a.toDataTable()`
which can be done when drawing the chart...

```
chart1a.draw(view1a.toDataTable(),ComboOpt);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
    google.charts.load('current',{callback:init,'packages':['corechart'],'language':'hr'});
    
    function init()
    {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date','Datum');
      data.addColumn('number','Vrijednost');
      data.addColumn('number','Relativna promjena');
      data.addColumn('number','Kontinuiranost promjene');
      data.addColumn('number','Prosjek obični u preth. 5 dana');
      data.addColumn('number','Prosjek težinski u preth. 5 dana');
      data.addColumn('number','Trend prema preth. 5 dana');
      data.addColumn('number','Prosjek obični u preth. 10 dana');
      data.addColumn('number','Prosjek težinski u preth. 10 dana');
      data.addColumn('number','Trend prema preth. 10 dana');
      data.addRows([
[new Date('2017-07-07'),11.92850,-0.13,-1,-3,-2.33333,11.96977,-5.5,-4,11.93431],
[new Date('2017-07-10'),11.94040,0.1,0,-3,-2.33333,11.9698,-5.5,-4,11.93224],
[new Date('2017-07-11'),11.96360,0.19,1,-3,-2.33333,11.95871,-5.5,-4,11.94423],
[new Date('2017-07-12'),11.95520,-0.07,0,-3,-2.33333,11.94968,-5.5,-4,11.96142],
[new Date('2017-07-13'),11.93310,-0.18,-1,-3,-2.33333,11.96335,-5.5,-4,11.97571],
[new Date('2017-07-14'),11.94130,0.07,0,-3,-2.33333,11.95136,-5.5,-4,11.97237],
[new Date('2017-07-17'),11.89760,-0.37,-1,-3,-2.33333,11.93811,-5.5,-4,11.96705],
[new Date('2017-07-18'),11.91230,0.12,0,-3,-2.33333,11.89439,-5.5,-4,11.93777],
[new Date('2017-07-19'),11.93750,0.21,1,-3,-2.33333,11.89151,-5.5,-4,11.91419],
[new Date('2017-07-20'),11.96080,0.2,2,-3,-2.33333,11.9183,-5.5,-4,11.9194],
[new Date('2017-07-21'),12.01040,0.41,3,-3,-2.33333,11.95357,-5.5,-4,11.93201],
[new Date('2017-07-24'),12.03320,0.19,4,-3,-2.33333,12.02595,-5.5,-4,11.95908],
[new Date('2017-07-25'),12.06780,0.29,5,-3,-2.33333,12.06525,-5.5,-4,11.99299],
[new Date('2017-07-26'),12.06780,0,5,-3,-2.33333,12.10184,-5.5,-4,12.04073],
[new Date('2017-07-27'),12.09690,0.24,6,-3,-2.33333,12.10942,-5.5,-4,12.07929],
[new Date('2017-07-28'),12.11120,0.12,7,-3,-2.33333,12.1175,-5.5,-4,12.11609],
[new Date('2017-07-31'),12.11100,-0,0,-3,-2.33333,12.13091,-5.5,-4,12.14988],
[new Date('2017-08-01'),12.14890,0.31,1,-3,-2.33333,12.12988,-5.5,-4,12.16061],
[new Date('2017-08-02'),12.06400,-0.7,0,-3,-2.33333,12.16005,-5.5,-4,12.17619],
[new Date('2017-08-03'),12.10260,0.32,1,-3,-2.33333,12.09797,-5.5,-4,12.14875]]);

      var ComboOpt = {
        height: 400,
        annotations: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}, highContrast: true},
        animation:{ duration: 500, easing: 'out', startup: true },
        vAxis: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}},
        hAxis: {textStyle: {fontName: 'Tahoma', fontSize: 9}, gridlines: {count: 30}, showTextEvery: 7},
        chartArea: {width: '80%', height: '80%'},
        legend: {position: 'bottom'},
        series: {0: {type: 'area', color: "blue", pointsVisible: true}, 
                 1: {type: 'line'}, 
                 2: {type: 'line'}}
      };
      
      var view1a = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view1a.setColumns([0,1,{sourceColumn:1,role:'annotation'},3,7]);
      var chart1a = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('Chart1a'));      
      chart1a.draw(view1a.toDataTable(),ComboOpt);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="Chart1a"></div>
```